# are memtable flush synced between nodes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I want to use incremental backup as backup strategy in my cassandra cluster, BUT I cannot understand, is flush process synchronized between nodes or each node flush himself.

For example :
I have table "ABC" with replica factor 2 and two nodes "A" and "B"

If "A" node memtable are full and going to be flushed to SSTable , then what will happened to node "B" with 33% usage of memtable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memtable flushes operate independently of each other.

When you run `nodetool flush`, it will only flush the memtables on the local node. Cheers!